# How to generate a picture like this?

Tags: plotting, image, generative-art

How to generate a picture like the following (from [Paolo Čerić's blog](http://patakk.tumblr.com/post/36055769499))? I'd like the surface of the manifold to randomly distort.

[image: animation]

Comment: Apparently this is from [Patakk](http://patakk.tumblr.com/post/36055769499)'s Tumblr blog.

Comment: next challenge could be to reproduce  the whole page http://patakk.tumblr.com/tagged/gif  ;-) keep us busy for a little while, not to mention copyright!

Comment: @chris Regarding copyright issues, from the blog: "_My work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License_"

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"]
poly = Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"], 4];

amplitude = 0.15;
twist = 4;
verts = poly[[1]];
faces = poly[[2]];
phases = RandomReal[2 Pi, Length[verts]];
newverts[t_] := 
  MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ (RotationMatrix[twist Last[#1]].Most[#1]), 
      Last[#1]} (1 + amplitude Sin[t + phases[[First@#2]]]) &, 
   verts];
newpoly[t_] := GraphicsComplex[newverts[t], faces];

duration = 1.5;
fps = 24;
frames = Most@
   Table[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], newpoly[t]}, 
     PlotRange -> Table[{-(1 + amplitude), (1 + amplitude)}, {3}], 
     ViewPoint -> Front, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False], {t, 0, 
     2 Pi, 2 Pi/(duration fps)}];
ListAnimate[frames, fps]
```

[image]

The next thing you need is [global illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_illumination), but Mathematica doesn't have that as far as I know.

Comment: Nice :) If anyone's interested, `"RedBlueTones"` or `"ThermometerColors"` will provide a decent approximation to the original colors. Choosing the color (from this palette) for each face based on the azimuthal angle might work.

Comment: Adding something like `Lighting -> {{"Point", 
   RGBColor[255/255, 89/255, 126/255], {-2, -1, -0.5}}, {"Point", 
   RGBColor[88/255, 210/255, 220/255], {2, -0.5, 0.5}}}` gives better lighting and maybe add some gray light.

Comment: quite nice! How did you upload the movie?

Comment: @chris I used `Export["ani.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.05]`.  If you *literally* mean upload there is an image button in the editor window toolbar which will let you select between uploading an image from your machine and using a URL.

Comment: A nice integration of POV-ray into Mathematica workflow would push the limits of this rendering

Answer (score 9):

This is a starter

```
dat = Table[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, -1, 1, 0.125}, {y, -1, 1, 0.125}, {z, -1, 1,  0.125}];

plots = Table[
noise = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.05], Dimensions[dat]];
Do[noise[[All, All, i]] *= 2, {i, 2, Length[noise] - 1, 2}];
ListContourPlot3D[dat + noise, Contours -> 1/2, Mesh -> False, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ContourStyle -> White ], {25}];

Export["test.gif", plots]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]