# How to make following feynman path integral simulation

Tags: graphics, programming, animation, simulation

I want to do the simulation of Feynman path integral which is given in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation#Path_integral_formula). How should I proceed?

Comment: Erm. This is not the way this site works. We are not going to do your job for you. Please have yourself a look for numerical methods of simulation. Then start to implement it. We can help with concrete problems with the implementation.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher but I have seen quite a lot of post where they put a request to get started/done with simulation for ex https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16383/how-to-generate-a-picture-like-this and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66967/how-do-you-create-such-an-animated-gif-via-mathematica

Comment: Yeah, but that was solvable in a dozen lines of code. You are asking for a simulation of Feynman's path integral. This is on a whole different complexity scale.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher okay let me put up the problems and code I have done to handle it.